# MongoDB change default port and restart service

Tags: windows, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB development environment, as first I am using Windows.

I am trying to set my port preferences on MongoDB, so I edit my port number at *mongod.cfg*

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 8888
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

and then I dig some research, it said that I need to restart my mongo database.
By typing this:
[image]

But I am a bit confused where to type this command, am I supposed to open another new command prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command `sudo ...` is a Linux command. In Windows you can start/stop a service in Windows Services Manager.

You open it either by command `services.msc` or got to "This PC right hand mouse button 
-> Manage -> Services"

You can also start/stop from command line:

```
net stop MongoDB
net start MongoDB
```

`MongoDB` is the default service name, you can set in your configuration file at

```
processManagement:
   windowsService:
      serviceName: <string>
      displayName: <string>
      description: <string>
```